# how to simply implement a KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private char c = 'e';
    public MyPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.repaint();
        g.drawString("the key that pressed is" + c, 250,250);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        c=e.getKeyChar();
        repaint();

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        c=e.getKeyChar();
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) yet didnt mange to understand how to simply implement a KeyListener. so what do i need to change for this to work?

Comment: What behavior would you expect from a working program?  If you want to change the on-screen string every time the user presses a key, a simple call to `repaint()` after every modification to `c` should do the trick.

Comment: yeah i forgot to add it, but it doesnt work anyway...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the reasons why it doesn't work:

1. The `JPanel` does not have the keyboard focus. (The frame has it.) You probably want to `requestFocus` when the panel is added to the screen.
2. You need to call `repaint` when the graphic should change.
3. You mustn't call `repaint` in the `paintComponent` method.
4. You need to clear the drawing area before drawing the string again (otherwise all characters will end up on top of each other).

Here's a complete working example:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private char c = 'e';

    public MyPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawString("the key that pressed is " + c, 250, 250);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        c = e.getKeyChar();
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Oh, and you may want to add `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` to make the application terminate when you close the window. :-)

Comment: This is what I call a great example!!